# Is SEO the most important part on making a website good?

Tags: seo

Can SEO be the only major part in making a website good? Cmon there are lots of facts, design, functionality, user friendly, efficient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps indirectly SEO can improve a website. It encourages you to think about quality content, good navigation and site usability.

But no, SEO itself does not make a website good or bad at all. In other words, **good SEO is a side-effect of a good website**.

Comment: Your last sentence is spot on

Comment: Nice reply, congrats.

Answer (score 1):

SEO is mostly:

- quality content
- usability
- accessibility
- semantic markup

If your site is built with the four principles in mind your site will be optimized for the search engines. If you have to go back and "SEO your website" then you made mistakes when you first built it and only are fixing it (or making it worse if your changes are only being made with the search engines in mind).

Once a properly built website is launched the only real SEO to be done is to utilize tools like Google Webmaster Tools to help facilitate the indexing of your site and find potential errors or problems that the search engines have with your site. Then from there it's continually adding new quality content (if applicable) and marketing (seeking links is marketing).

Answer (score 1):

A good website has, IMHO:

- Good content
- Good accessibility
- Good design
- Good usability

Make site findable is important, but making visitors like a site after find it depends on other things.

On page SEO basically depends on 2 of four factors I listed (content and accessibility), plus semantic markup, plus friendly URLs. Except content, other points are technical.

Content, usability and design are the factors that make your site interesting and pleasant. Without them, your site can be find, but can't achieve goals or help out people, thus making it a bad website.

So, I think SEO is important, but content (be it a copy text, an idea or a service) and usability are more important than findability as measure to a good website.-

Answer (score 1):

No it's not, but **If you try to sell something on the web, SEO is the most important part!!!**

**Nowdays** even if you have super efficent server and well designed, with great functionality and user friendlysness, efficient website, **but you do not appear in 1st Google page, you won't get any orders!!!**

This said, it's absolutely true that it's easier to do SEO on well designed, with great functionality and user friendlysness, efficient, **full of rich interesting contents**  websites rather than doing SEO on poorly designed, slow, poor contents, websites.

So a well designed webiste can be considered a necessary start conditon for good SEO, but not sufficient. You might still find poor designed webistes that ranks higher that your well designed website on Google and they will sell more than your website.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no. But what do you mean by 'good'. Not a great question. A website has many aspects all of which should be attended well to make a superior quality site.

Answer (score 0):

SEO does not 'make a website good', *per se*.

SEO can help a good website get better exposure via search engines, obviously. But a 'bad' website can equally benefit from SEO.

However, SEO is improved by many of the techniques that feature in good websites: appropriate, valid semantic markup, good content, accessibility, etc.

So good design improves SEO, but SEO doesn't necessarily improve the website.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new in SEO, and my knowledge is based on forums such as this and some articles I found over the web - but I want to share an interesting fact from my experience.

I have an ecommerce website that didn't do so good. There is LOTS of sense in the way Google ranks and promotes your website. The Google bots are actually good quite human, if they would like your site then humans would like it.

The SEO knowledge got me to completely change the design of my website making it a lot more user friendly. Besides for the fact that I do get a lot more traffic (but never enough :) ), the users are actually buying since it is easier to find their way around the site. Before the site was pretty and now it is effective!